# Call function inside bxslider callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, bxslider

I am trying to call a custom function inside a bxslider callback but the function doesn't get recorgnized (aka: **Uncaught Reference Error: nextSlideCustom() is not a function**)

my current code looks like

```
    var slider=$('#slider1').bxSlider({
         pager: 'true',
         onSlideNext: nextSlideHandle()
    });
```

and in a different js file I am defining this function:

```
function nextSlideHandle(){
    console.log("huhu");
}
```

so what's the problem with my code, or is it mory likely a wrong configuration of the slider or something?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

make sure `nextSlideHandle` is defined before calling `bxSlider`, and also do it without parantheses, because that way, you're passing the result of the function and not the function itself, hence; undefined function error.

```
var slider=$('#slider1').bxSlider({
     pager: 'true',
     onSlideNext: nextSlideHandle
});
```

Comment: thank you for you reply!! 

actually it is before the call of bxslider, but never the less, its acting like that.... 

could there be any other reason?

Comment: with the information you have provided, i can't think of any.